# Magento 2 admin error 404 page not found and admin url is also not found

Tags: magento-2.0

[image]

[image]

I use all the methods available on google but nothing worked. Same issue is showing again and again.

After running this command: `php bin/magento info:adminuri`. It does not show the admin url.

Comment: Could you please share some of your methods that you already tried, because there are a lot of reasons why (admin url is not found)?

Have you already tried this [link](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-backend-is-not-working.html)

and what's the URL of your admin page?

Comment: Try this:
`php bin/magento info:adminuri`



`Admin URI: /admin`

Comment: my url address is : http://magento.local/admin

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean ,
rm -rf var/cache/* ,
rm -rf var/generation/* ,
this commands i tried 
and that's another link i tried : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133679/404-not-found-error-for-admin-page.

plz tell me if you find something . thanks

Comment: Please check app/etc/env.php file and search for 'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),  is it admin or something else?

Comment: Try this http://magento2.local/index.php/admin if it doesn’t work too then please share error log

Answer (score 5):

1. Check for the admin URL in the app/etc/env.php. For example, it can be something like this (Is it frontName empty in your case?). Change the frontname to your preference, clean cache and try again.

   ```
   return array (
     'backend' => 
     array (
       'frontName' => 'admin_1onald',
     ),
   ```
2. Check the core_config_data table to find if admin url has been changed from the admin panel

   `select * from core_config_data where path like '%custom%';`

check if there are any records for

`- admin/url/use_custom
 - admin/url/custom
 - admin/url/use_custom_path
 - admin/url/custom_path`

If any, adjust > cache clean > try again

Comment: return array ( 'backend' => array ( 'frontName' => 'admin_1onald', ),

i also try this method but nothing happened. and for these

admin/url/use_custom
admin/url/custom
admin/url/use_custom_path
admin/url/custom_path

there are no records in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Change the admin URL of your store. Run the following command in the root directory of your store:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="newadmin"
```

In the above command, I have set the admin name **newadmin** so to access the admin panel add /newadmin with your store URL.